# How to start gnome-control-center. If symbol lookup error: libgoa-backend-1.0.so.1?

Tags: 17.10, settings, symbolic-link, gnome-control-center

1. Tried to run `gnome-control-center`.
2. But there is error `gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgoa-backend-1.0.so.1: undefined symbol: g_uuid_string_random`
3. Updated from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10. Before it worked well.
4. Tried to reinstall it, but it didn't help.
5. Here someone faced [this problem](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=854139) and solved, but I tried it and no success.
6. The output of `ldd /usr/bin/gnome-control-center` (correct lines are removed by N0rbert) :

   ```
   ...
   libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f557b3c9000)
   ...
   libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f557a38a000)
   ...
   libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5579b87000)
   ...
   ```

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1007016/edit) your question and add output of `ldd /usr/bin/gnome-control-center` to it.

Comment: @N0rbert Did it. It looks like very huge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to reinstall the package containing `libgoa-backend-1.0.so.1.0.0`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgoa-backend-1.0-1
```

According to your ldd output you have some strange libraries:

```
/usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
```

You should move them out the way:

```
mkdir ~/usr_local_lib
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0 ~/usr_local_lib
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 ~/usr_local_lib
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 ~/usr_local_lib
```

For predictable results it is recommended to reinstall packages of these libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libatk1.0-0 libglib2.0-0
```

You may want to investigate `/usr/local/lib/` folder further.

Comment: Hello @N0rbert, Thank you for response. There is still this error yet.

Comment: Updated your question and my answer - you have 3 libraries in `/usr/local/lib`, all other libraries are in correct place.

Comment: Great! It is working now! As you said I moved those 3 `.so` from `/usr/local/lib/`. Thank you very much!